# Как убрать ввод кавычек двойным нажатием? (IntelliJ Idea)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, кавычки

С обновлением до JDK 21.0.2 вводить кавычки стало возможным только при двойном нажатии на кнопку кавычки. Раньше для этого было достаточно одного нажатия.
Кто-нибудь знает, можно ли как-то вернуть назад, чтобы не нужно было нажимать на клавишу кавычки два раза?

Я облазил все настройки, но ничего про кавычки не нашёл.
Может я не там искал? Подскажите где искать, пожалуйста.

Comment: По описанию больше похоже на [Dead keys](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8). Вы точно настройки раскадок клавиатуры не меняли?

Comment: Немного менял. Сейчас у меня английский INT, а не USA.

Comment: Ну тогда это 99.99% dead keys. И вообще-то должно проявляться везде, а не только в идее

Comment: JDK не влияет на то сколько вам нужно нажимать количество раз кавычки, скорее всего Dead keys, в ту сторону надо копать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Дело было в раскладке клавиатуры.